# Timer counter in finite loop in php

Tags: php

I want a timer counter in php example 1567 which will increment every second 
and it goes till infinite even if some body refresh the page it counter will not starts from 1567 .but it should starts for where its is end.

Comment: why you want to do something like this? it is not good idea to make infinity loop. better use cron job.

Comment: actually client wants that

Comment: You can't do this in PHP. Not to make it update like a clock at least

Comment: can you suggest me on that which language i should used that.

Comment: infity loop will down the server. so better use cron job. it is much better. search for `cron job`

Comment: JavaScript and a difference between your start number and Unix clock

Comment: here is my site reference it was working but not properly.

Comment: or can i used in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is the general idea of what you need.

If you first start by taking the Unix time of the day the client want to count from then add the magic 1567.
Now this will be the start, if we take now in unix-start we get the counter value as it's currently (with the 1567).

If you add this to the JavaScript code that outputs it and adds one to it each second then you are done.

```
$start = strtotime("2019-04-15 12:05") + 1567;

echo time()-$start;
```

https://3v4l.org/B0v2M

Comment: thank it works .but when i try to used change 54021234 but it gives a -54021235

Comment: Most likely that is because you reach the maximum integer number and the number rolls over to negative.

Comment: so how can i solve to that

Comment: That is your problem! You asked for 1567. You got 1567. If your plan was to use a number that is about 54 millions then it's a poorly formulated question

Comment: actually client want to starts from 54021234

Comment: Ok that's good information to you, and very useful information **in the question from start**. Not added after.